# Data trim regex

Tags: regex, r, trim

I'm new to regex and r, 
and trying to clear my dataframe that contains column A.

```
      A
"111  222 AAA2"
"11  23 BBB1" 
"101  33 CC3"
```

The first blank contains two blank and second blank only contains one, 
and the length of the strings can vary. I would like to get the last word, that comes after the second blank.

The output dataframe would be

```
 A
AAA2
BBB1
CC3
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you just trying to get anything that comes after the last space? Please define your "rules" more precisely and use the correct terminology (you have vectors here, not a `data.frame`).

Comment: This regex `([A-Z]+\d+)` will capture constants you want.

Comment: @apgp88 and how would one use that in r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) read.table** Use `read.table` and take 3rd column:

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = c("111  222 AAA2", "11  23 BBB1", "101  33 CC3"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
read.table(text = DF$V1, as.is = TRUE)[[3]]
```

giving:

```
[1] "AAA2" "BBB1" "CC3"
```

**2) sub** If you really want to use a regex then this removes everything up to and including the last space giving the same result:

```
sub(".* ", "", DF$V1)
```

Here is a visualization of the regex:

```
.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hsJeZsLrGPBh6PMQ)

Comment: I just edited the input file format, I'm reading it from a csv file that contains a column that contains one data in each line, and it doesn't work.. Is there any other way?

Comment: figured it out by using gsub(^[^A-Z]+), "", data[,1]) thanks!

Comment: @user2418838 I had posted that as an answer before bu that only works if the last chunk doesn't uses caps letters and no caps appear before this.

Answer (score 0):

This could work if I understand your rules:

```
x <- c("111  222 AAA2", "11  23 BBB1", "101  33 CC3")

gsub("^[^A-Z]+", "", x)
## [1] "AAA2" "BBB1" "CC3"
```